# Multiplication algorithm using Bitshifts

Tags: c, algorithm, multiplication

While looking for a efficient algorithm for multiplying 2 large numbers, came across the below c method in a forum:-

```
...
    typedef unsigned long long ULL;

    ULL multiply (ULL a,ULL b)
    {
      ULL result = 0;
      while(a > 0)
      {
        if(a & 1)
        {
          result += b;
        }
        a >>= 1;
        b <<= 1;    
      }

      return result;
    }
...
```

The above algo doesn't require multiply instruction, rather uses bitshift and addition operation only (thus making it quicker).

Checked that the method is working correctly, but, I don't fully get how it works. An explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Note some CPUs can have terribly slow shift operations - 68008 used to be an example. So your mileage may vary.

Comment: "thus making it quicker" - in a not way

Comment: The algorithm is the same thing you learned in school for long multiplication; except the first operand is taken in base 2. It's sometimes called "Russian multiplication"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's iterating over all the 1 bits in `a`, adding `b` shifted the appropriate amount.

First, note that if `a` is `11001`, it can be treated as `10000` + `1000` + `1`, so `a * b` is `(10000*b) + (1000*b) + (1*b)`.
Then, note that `10000*b` is just `b << 4`.

Each time through the loop, `b` is shifted left by 1 to reflect the current shift amount, and `a` is shifted right by 1 so that the low-order bit can be tested.  In this example, it ends up adding `b` + `(b << 3)` + `(b << 4)`, which is just `(1*b) + (1000*b) + (10000*b)`.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, it is nice algorithm, and similar to what we do by hand:

```
123*  
456=  
6*(123)+  
50*(123)+ //this means one digit shift, nice and easy  
400*(123) //this means two digits shift, nice and easy
```

So let’s do binary:

```
101*  //b  
110=  //a  
0*(101)+    
10*(101)+ //=1*(1010) //one digit shift  
100*(101) //=1*(10100) //two digits shift
```

**a** shifted right to access its first bit by: **if(a&1)**
**b** shifted left for every position to do one digit shift same as above

**This is exactly what we do when multiplying by hand**

I am suggesting to use **uint64_t** from

```
#include<stdint.h>
```

for good and clear coding style:

```
#include<stdint.h> 
uint64_t multiply(uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    uint64_t result = 0;
    while (a > 0)
    {
        if (a & 1)
        {
            result += b;
        }
        a >>= 1;
        b <<= 1;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    uint64_t a = 123;
    uint64_t b = 456;
    uint64_t c = multiply(a, b);
}
```